# Auth cookie, Azure Web Sites and DNS Failover

Tags: .net, azure, forms-authentication, failover

I have two Azure Web Sites in two different regions with AWS Route 53 set as DNS Failover (I think Azure Traffic Manager would be the same).

Is there a way to share auth cookie between the two sites?

Comment: Yes, there is. What is the concrete programming problem that you have and what have you tried so far to accomplish your goal?

Comment: I'd need to keep the user logged in even if he lands on website #2 (and logged in in website #1) but as far as I know I cannot set machine key in web.config.