# Unit testing DNS failover, using a custom DNS resolver

Tags: .net, unit-testing, dns

I came recently across an interesting article [Unit testing DNS failovers](http://onoffswitch.net/unit-testing-dns-failovers/) (inspired by [Local Managed DNS (Java)](http://rkuzmik.blogspot.fi/2006/08/local-managed-dns-java_11.html). Though I would be much interested to know if there is a way in .NET to arrange for arranging a custom resolution source, but it doesn't look like so.

I tried to look around if [System.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481553.aspx) in general and [DNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) in particular provie something for this. There are some questions in SO and elsewhere (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227863/dns-lookup-from-custom-dns-server-in-c-sharp) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702205/auth-cookie-azure-web-sites-and-dns-failover) tangentially and [Specifying the name servers for System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry()](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b5fe9a3-5da0-41e0-a7f9-2cb6c5608f69/specifying-the-name-servers-for-systemnetdnsgethostentry?forum=ncl) on MSDN forums) to this direction, but they offer using a custom DNS libraries which the .NET framework components cannot be made to use.

The linked articles give some more rounded rationale as to why this would desirable in some testing scenarios. Does someone know a way even if it would involve P/Invoke?

**<edit 2016-08-30:** Related to [Singleton HttpClient doesn't respect DNS changes](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11224) and the blog posts linked from there [Singleton HttpClient? Beware of this serious behaviour and how to fix it](http://byterot.blogspot.fi/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html) and [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). These give nice context on why one might want to use a singleton and what potential trouble it will cause, consequently making it more important to test these scenarios.

Comment: are you trying to get a customized DNS working in .NET? Or, you want to do testing of a resolver's failover, or test failover in a DNS server. I'm not against someone writing a new DNS resolver, but the two times I've seen it done, the coder was taking a shortcut, and lacked the patience, or managerial support to code a proper resolver. Both were ended after a rash of P1 from the daily build and inside customers.

Comment: Original blog is down, archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20161010092216/http://onoffswitch.net/unit-testing-dns-failovers/